# C++ going from running a switch to a if statement afterwards

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

In c++ Im trying to use a if statement after a switch statement. How do I run the if because it's not running it. The switch just runs.

The Output is:

```
492.5
490
487.5
485
482.5
480
477.5
475
472.5
470
467.5
```

the next output is decreased by -2.5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double A(5), B(5), C(0), D(7.5), E(20), V(495), F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P;

    for (int t = 0; t <= 10; t = t + 1)
    {
        switch (t)
        {
            case 0:
            F = A + B + C + D - E + V;
            cout << F << endl;
            break;

            case 1:
            G = A + B + C + D - E + F;
            cout << G << endl;
            break;

            case 2:
            H = A + B + C + D - E + G;
            cout << H << endl;
            break;

            case 3:
            I = A + B + C + D - E + H;
            cout << I << endl;
            break;

            case 4:
            J = A + B + C + D - E + I;
            cout << J << endl;
            break;

            case 5:
            K = A + B + C + D - E + J;
            cout << K << endl;
            break;

            case 6:
            L = A + B + C + D - E + K;
            cout << L << endl;
            break;

            case 7:
            M = A + B + C + D - E + L;
            cout << M << endl;
            break;

            case 8:
            N = A + B + C + D - E + M;
            cout << N << endl;
            break;

            case 9: 
            O = A + B + C + D - E + N;
            cout << O << endl;
            break;

            case 10:
            P = A + B + C + D - E + O;
            cout << P << endl;
            break;

            case 11:
            if (B = B + 5)
            {
                F = A + B + C + D - E + V;
                G = A + B + C + D - E + F;
                H = A + B + C + D - E + G;
                I = A + B + C + D - E + H;
                J = A + B + C + D - E + I;
                K = A + B + C + D - E + J;
                L = A + B + C + D - E + K;
                M = A + B + C + D - E + L;
                N = A + B + C + D - E + M;

                cout << F << endl;
                cout << G << endl;
                cout << H << endl;
                cout << I << endl;
                cout << J << endl;
                cout << K << endl;
                cout << L << endl;
                cout << M << endl;
                cout << N << endl;

            }
        }

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `if (B = B + 5)` -- are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Combining a `for` loop and a `switch` in this manner seems contradictory. You might have simpler code if you just spell out each case sequentially, the `for` loop seems to just iterate over each one in turn anyway. There's a lot going on here so simplicity is essential.

Comment: How do you even keep track of all those alphabet-style single-letter variables?

Comment: Since B = 5 already. If it was b plus b then It would equal to 10 an output the next set of numbers after the first?

Comment: @FredLarson, there is no way to make this `if` right. It's plain nonsense.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, I agree.

Comment: I kind of figure it was a cooky myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` statement ends at `t == 10`..

```
for (int t = 0; t <= 10; t = t + 1)
```

And your `if` is somewhere in the `case` of `t` being 11.

```
......
case 10:
P = A + B + C + D - E + O;
cout << P << endl;
break;
case 11:
if (B == B + 5)
{
.....
```

So, raise the `for-loop` termination condition from `10` to `11`...

And and there is something wrong with your if. even if you meant below:

```
.....
if(B == B + 5) {     //doing if(B = B + 5) is adding 5 to B and checking whether its not 0
.....
```

Comment: What would be the point of such an `if`?

Comment: to increase the value of 10 .

Comment: How would `B` be equal to `B + 5`? `B` is equal to `B`, `B + 5` is equal to `B + 5`. If you have some money in your wallet, you can't have the same amount of money after you put in additional 5 bucks.

Comment: @SergeyA, answer modified. #SMH ....

Comment: B is initially declared as 5 that's why I did B = B+5. I was just guessing a condition for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

it is not working because you're assigning a value to B instead of check,

change this line:

```
if (B = B + 5)
```

to

```
if (B == B + 5)
```

it should work :)

Comment: It ran however I didn't get any values to print out. is there something wrong with cout statments.@Salma

Comment: When would `(B == B + 5)` be true?